# GCM Android API is considered a third party software?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my app, I mention all third party software I am using in the About page. Should I also mention Google cloud messaging which I am also using?

Comment: The term "third party software" basically means that the software is from another entity. What I can say is if you are not from Google, then yes GCM Android API is a third party software in your case. Here is a good definition that I found regarding the term "[third party](http://techterms.com/definition/thirdparty)".

Answer (score 0):

GCM is part of Google Play Services so it should be treated as third party. Here is some documentation about the attribution required for the Maps API (which is also part of Google Play Services)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro#attribution_requirements